# how to create a script that gets executed when Ubuntu boots

Tags: 14.04, boot, scripts

I am new to Ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to write a script that is being executed when ubuntu boots.

so my script file gunicorn.sh looks like this

```
cd /path/to/folder/with/manage.py/
exec gunicorn --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.my_settings app.wsgi
```

I made it excutable and now when I run it using this

```
./gunicorn.sh
```

it works. Now I placed it into

```
/etc/init.d
```

and did this

```
sudo update-rc.d -f gunicorn.sh defaults
```

and I got this message

> update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing insserv: warning:
>   script 'gunicorn.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides which I found out
>   is not important.

However, when I boot it doesn't work, it's not executing the script

Comment: Just add those commands to /ewtc/init.d/rc.local (create the file if you wish). The error message you are getting are because you did not write a proper init script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I added it to the top of the rc.local. I also found it as a solution in the pi doc https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Ok, I did put it in but I realized it's not going to last long. The gunicorn command gets exectued and then it stops at some point. How do I do it that it  doesn't get stopped?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you need to add LSB tags to the script. See here:

https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

An easier way to do this do is just to add a new startup application. Search "Startup Applications" in the dashboard and point to your script. This way you can keep it anywhere you want.

[image: example]

Comment: Hi, thanks but i can't you the startup program, I am exclusivley using the terminal for this project